# Python yml profile only read

Tags: python, yaml

I have a .yml file with this structure by instance:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter: DEBUG
mambu:
   connectiontimeout: 20000
   receivetimeout: 20000


---
spring:
  profiles: local
saraza:
  api:
    url: 'http://0.0.0.0'
    path: '/saraza'
---
spring:
  profiles: local2
saraza:
  api:
    url: 'http://0.0.0.2'
    path: '/saraza2'
```

Now I would like to make a dictionary with only the settings provided at profile 'local'. I wrote this function:

```
def app_config():
    """
    Returns app targets settings
    """
    with open('app.yml', 'r') as stream:
        documents = yaml.load_all(stream)

        # Keep only local profile
        settings =  [doc for doc in documents if doc['spring']['profiles'] == 'local'][0]
    return settings
```

But when it is executed I get:

```
.0 = <generator object load_all at 0x7f0ff9383c50>

>   settings = [doc for doc in documents if doc['spring']['profiles'] == 'local'][0]
E   KeyError: 'spring'

conftest.py:21: KeyError
```

Best regards

Comment: The dashes indicate three separate documents in one file. Why not *split* on it, and parse each one separately?

Comment: Yeah that could work.

Comment: @jonsharpe I use that as solution and it is fine, if you want to post the answer it will be correct. Thanks!

Comment: But that's not what the question asks any more. You could avoid the key error with e.g. `doc.get('spring', {})`, or  `'spring' in doc and ...`.

Comment: Yes, please don't change your question to a completely different question. Your original question was about how to handle a stream of multiple YAML documents, which I answered correctly. Your new question relates to matters of processing Python data structures parsed from the YAML and should really be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The `---` is a [document prefix](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800168) that is a normal part of YAML syntax. If you remove it then the multiple documents in that file are combined into one, and now you have duplicate map keys. Since you're reading a file that contains multiple documents you should use `yaml.load_all()` which will parse all the documents and return them in a list. What you do with that list of documents depends on the needs of your use case.

Comment: How can I access for example to the second keys (profile local2) with the returned object?

Comment: I don't know what this data pertains to or what you're trying to do with it. If you wanted to get all the values associated with the "profiles" key in each document you would do something like `profiles = [doc['spring']['profiles'] for doc in documents]`.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to get the profiles but I can not loop "documents". I am getting several errors. Can you add to the answer how to manage the output of `yaml.load_all(strean)`

Comment: In other words, each of these documents is, by itself à map (which in Python is called a `dict`). So a file containing multiple documents could, in this case, be considered a list of `dict`s. In JSON this would just be represented as `[{...}, {...}, ...]`. In YAML you can also have a list of maps, but the "document" syntax has a semantic meaning that each document represents a sort of self-contained mutually independent record of some kind. Those semantics are baked into the syntax in JSON. It also allows different tag namespaces per document, etc., but that isn't used in your example.

Comment: Apparently not all the documents in your file contain a 'spring' key, so you have to ignore those that don't, probably using an `if` statement.